# Swaping elements with transition in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of elements, where each element is an object with attribute 'vote'. In the view, I am displaying the elements in the sorted fashion based on 'vote'. Now when some person votes a particular element, I increment the vote and the elements in the view gets sorted. But it get sorted very quick. How can I add some visual animations like, it should look like the elements are being swapped. All I want is, this reactivly sorting of the elements should be little slow, so that user can watch it.

Comment: Can you please post some code or Plunker so i have better idea and can give solution? Plunker or Js fiddle is better.

Comment: As Karan mentioned yes please provide a Plnkr or something with your sample. To animate or delay displaying your changes you can try to call a function in lieu or directly changing your variables, which handles a timeout and apply animation classes.